# 2K8 Cluster - SQL Instance broken on one node

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, windows-cluster

Using a 2-nodes cluster 2008R2 Failover Cluster. A new clustered instance was created (I double checked it's clustered).

Instance was installed on node1. When we try to move it to node2, it failed. SQL Server service won't start saying :

`Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion`

When I first try to debug it, it appears that in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\`, there were no MyInstance folder one the second node...
First question: is that normal ?

So I decided to copy/paste this folder from node1 -> node2. Service started good after a reboot of node2.
The day after, I decided to move my Instance back to node1 -> OK. I now move it to node2, error. And I got the error mentionned above..

I can't start this service one node2, but everything is OK on node1. I've compare regedit from both, and there are exactly the same.

No luck with EventViewer, so I really don't know how to troubleshoot this problem.

EDIT: With SQL Server Configuration manager, Node1 I can see MyInstance but not on Node2 ... if it can help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your SQL Setup again on node2 after installing a new cluster on node1. Select the option 'Add a node to a SQL Server failover Cluster'

[image]
(screenshot from 2012, but the process is the same)